# How can I count unique values in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I have these tables:

Table 1:

[image]

Table 2:

[image]

The column 'Acertos' (the last one) in the table 1 counts how many values of the table 2 contains in it, in other words, when I add a number into the table 2, the column 'Acertos' will check to see if such number exists in the range `B-H`.

I am using this formula: `=SUM(COUNTIF($O$2:$T$6,C2:H2))`

It sort of does what I want, but it also counts the repeated values. As you can see, `Ana` only hit 2 and 4, so, `Acertos` should be 2, but since there are three 4 and two 2 in the table 2, `Acertos` is counting 5.

I found this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJFeQQOfu0k&ab_channel=dptutorials

It counts only unique numbers, but it only checks the table based on the numbers that still are in there, I need to check it based on another table.

I've tried to make some adaptations but without any success, since I am new on Excel and I am a bit lost.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula in Table 1:

```
=SUM(INT(COUNTIF($O$2:$T$6,Table1[@[Num 1]:[Num 6]])>0))
```

Your original `COUNTIF` gives this:

[image]

Making it "unique", you just test if each cell in the array is greater than zero, like this:

[image]

Convert it back into 1 and 0:

[image]

And then sum to give the final formula.

Comment: It works great. Thank you very much!!